# Reorder multidimensional array by list of IDs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that is from a JSON API:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "anchor": "Atkins Diet Coupon",
            "status": "viewed",
            "points": 0,
            "latest_date": 1432135046,
            "created_date": 1432134221,
            "contacted": true
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "anchor": "Videostripe",
            "status": "viewed",
            "points": 0,
            "latest_date": 1432134545,
            "created_date": 1432131231,
            "contacted": false
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "anchor": "Smilebox",
            "status": "viewed",
            "points": 0,
            "latest_date": 1432053140,
            "created_date": 1432131131,
            "contacted": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I convert it using the following PHP code:

```
$data = file_get_contents($api_url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

I have a list of ids that I want to have displayed first in the multidimensional array:

```
$ids = array('1','6');
```

So in this example: the multidimensional array would be reordered with 1,6,7 based on the order of the ids array, and then reverting back to its original order if not featured in the ids array.

This is a very complicated thing and I'm not sure at all how to do it!

Comment: So, basically you just want 1 and 6 first and the rest later right?

Comment: yep, but reordering so all the data follows with the ids - rather than just changing the ids

Comment: I answered below... Let me know if anything else is required :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort` to specify your own rules for sorting.

For example:

```
$ids = array('1','6');
usort($data["data"], function ($a, $b) use ($ids) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['id'], $ids);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['id'], $ids);
    if ($pos_a === FALSE && $pos_b === FALSE) {
        return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    }
    if ($pos_a === FALSE) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($pos_b === FALSE) {
        return -1;
    }
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This I believe is a cleaner code :)

```
$ids = [1,6];

sort($ids); // Optional (For cases where you mistakenly write [1,7,6])

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
  return $a['id'] > $b['id'];
});

$ordered = array_filter($data, function($arrayData) use ($ids) {
  return (in_array($arrayData['id'], $ids));
});

$unordered = array_filter($data, function($arrayData) use ($ids) {
  return (!in_array($arrayData['id'], $ids));
});

$finalArray = array_merge($ordered, $unordered);
```

Glad to help :)

Comment: Firstly, you have to make closure for `$ids` like this `function($arrayData) use ($ids)`. Secondly, your solution **does not reoder the elements**. It simply puts elements which `'id'` is present in the `$ids` array first, disregarding the order.

Comment: @sevavietl Firstly, yes, I know, I was actually writing in a new page in my ATOM IDE, so forgot about the `use ($ids)` part while writing.... Secondly, this will never disregard the order... array_filter is meant to takeout/remove the non-required id fields from the $data table from their respective positions and then array_merge simply puts the ordered one before unordered one... And that is what I believe the questionnaire asked for... (as discussed in the question comments)

Comment: @prateekkathal, OP wrote *"the multidimensional array would be reordered with 1,6,7 based on the order of the ids array"*. I ran your code, it will give the order 6,1,7. And it is expected, because `array_filter` **only filters, but not sets an order**.

Comment: @sevavietl Oh yes, I agree.... Definitely missed that... fixed it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another array with first values from your ID array and then other elements. You can create a custom function to get the key of the element from the array associated with the value of ID . Below code may help you. This is not fixed for (1,6). This is general solution. You can put any order, any number of elements.

```
<?php
 $data = '{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "anchor": "Atkins Diet Coupon",
        "status": "viewed",
        "points": 0,
        "latest_date": 1432135046,
        "created_date": 1432134221,
        "contacted": true
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "anchor": "Videostripe",
        "status": "viewed",
        "points": 0,
        "latest_date": 1432134545,
        "created_date": 1432131231,
        "contacted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "anchor": "Smilebox",
        "status": "viewed",
        "points": 0,
        "latest_date": 1432053140,
        "created_date": 1432131131,
        "contacted": false
    }
]
}';
```

Convert to array, create ids array,initialize a reorder array

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$ids= array(1,6);
$array_elements = $data['data'];
$reordered_array=array();
```

Use foreach to fill the re-ordered array with the ids from the array.Use custom function to find the element. Remove the moved elements from the array. then merge them together.

```
foreach($ids as $id)
{
  $get_key =  mycustfunction($array_elements,'id',$id);
  $reordered_array[] = $array_elements[$get_key];
  unset($array_elements[$get_key]);
}
$result_array = array_merge($reordered_array,$array_elements);
print_r($result_array);
```

Custom function

```
function mycustfunction($products, $field, $value)
{
  foreach($products as $key => $product)
  {
     if ( $product[$field] === $value )
     return $key;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];

// Convert the values into keys for convenience.
// It is easy to check if ID exists with isset($keys[$id]).
$keys = array_flip($ids);

// Collect items $ids
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  // Search for an item with this ID
  foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {
    if ($item['id'] == $id) {
      $result []= $item;
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Collect the rest of the items
foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {
  if (!isset($keys[$item['id']]))
    $result []= $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the data to the ids. Then loop over `$ids` and grab the corresponded data in order of id appearance in the array, also unset founded `$data` elements. Then append the elements left in the `$data` to the end of the array containing founded elements.

```
$data = array_combine(
    array_column($response['data'], 'id'),
    $response['data']
);

$keyed = array_map(function ($id) use (&$data) {
    if (isset($data[$id])) {
        $datum = $data[$id];
        unset($data[$id]);

        return $datum;
    }

    return null;
}, $ids);

$data = array_values($keyed + $data);
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fddfae61e0504cbd2b72a8ba7af1c34deab5927).

Note that when there's no element with te given `id` the `null` values will be placed.